# SQL Scalar function running long time from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

Below scalar function called from stored procedure.but The stored procedure 
 running very slow. I 
 dont know what mistake i have done below function.Please help me to find what 
 mistake done. Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[GInterval](@App_ID int, @Setting_ID int,@Entity_ID 
  int, @Item_ID int)
  RETURNS int 
 AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @SIntVal    int
DECLARE @Error      int
/* This code snipit is taken directly from GInterval because
   stored procedures can not be called from within functions*/

DECLARE @SP_Nme                 varchar(40)
DECLARE @H_Base             int
DECLARE @S_Ent_ID           int
DECLARE @S_Itm_ID               int
DECLARE @AppEntSet_Act  int
DECLARE @AppEntSVal_Act int
DECLARE @Appl_Item_ID       int
DECLARE @Usr_Ent_ID             int
DECLARE @Cl_Ent_ID          int
DECLARE @Ofc_Ent_ID         int
DECLARE @PrsCenter_Ent_ID   int
DECLARE @Appl_Ent_ID        int
DECLARE @UpstreamHit                tinyint
DECLARE @SrcEnt_ID              INT

DECLARE @Appl_ID_loc int
DECLARE @Set_ID_loc  int
DECLARE @Ent_ID_loc  int
DECLARE @Itm_ID_loc  int

SELECT @Appl_ID_loc=@App_ID, @Set_ID_loc=@Setting_ID, 
@Ent_ID_loc=@Entity_ID, @Itm_ID_loc=@Item_ID

SET     @SP_Nme                 = Object_Name(@@PROCID)
SET     @Usr_Ent_ID             = 1
SET     @Cl_Ent_ID          = 2
SET     @Ofc_Ent_ID         = 3
SET     @PrsCenter_Ent_ID   = 4
SET     @Appl_Ent_ID        = 5
SET     @AppEntSet_Act  = 297
SET     @AppEntSVal_Act = 299
SET     @UpstreamHit                = 0

SET @SIntVal=NULL
SET @SrcEnt_ID=NULL

SELECT  @SIntVal = AESV.intVal,
        @SrcEnt_ID = @Ent_ID_loc
FROM    GEICO.dbo.ApplicationEntitySettingVal AESV  
WHERE   AESV.Application_ID =  @Appl_ID_loc
AND AESV.Setting_ID = @Set_ID_loc
AND AESV.Entity_ID = @Ent_ID_loc
AND AESV.Status_ID = @AppEntSVal_Act
AND AESV.Item_ID = @Itm_ID_loc

IF @@error <> 0 
BEGIN
    RETURN -999999999
END

IF ((@SIntVal IS NULL) AND (@SrcEnt_ID IS NULL))
BEGIN



    SELECT  @H_Base = HierarchyRank
    FROM    GEICO.dbo.ApplicationEntitySetting AES  
    WHERE   AES.Application_ID =  @Appl_ID_loc
    AND AES.Setting_ID = @Set_ID_loc
    AND AES.Entity_ID = @Ent_ID_loc

    IF @H_Base IS NULL
        SET @H_Base = 0

    DECLARE @upstream_temp TABLE (Entity_ID INT, Item_ID INT)   

    INSERT INTO @upstream_temp(Entity_ID,Item_ID)
    SELECT   Entity_ID,Item_ID FROM GEICO.dbo.fn_Setting_GetUpstreamIDs(@Ent_ID_loc, @Itm_ID_loc)

    DECLARE SettingChk cursor LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
    FOR
        SELECT  Entity_ID
        FROM    GEICO.dbo.ApplicationEntitySetting AES  
        WHERE   AES.Application_ID =  @Appl_ID_loc
        AND AES.Setting_ID = @Set_ID_loc
        AND AES.Status_ID = @AppEntSVal_Act
        AND AES.HierarchyRank > @H_Base
        ORDER BY    AES.HierarchyRank


    OPEN SettingChk

    WHILE (10=10)
    BEGIN

        FETCH NEXT
        FROM    SettingChk
        INTO    @Search_Entity_ID

        IF (@@fetch_status <> 0)
        BEGIN
            CLOSE SettingChk
            DEALLOCATE SettingChk
            BREAK
        END



        SELECT  @S_Itm_ID = Item_ID FROM    @upstream_temp
        WHERE Entity_ID = @S_Ent_ID

        --Need to get application ID since it was not returned by the function of getupstreamids.
        if @S_Ent_ID = @Appl_Ent_ID 
            SELECT  @S_Itm_ID =  @Appl_ID_loc


        IF @S_Itm_ID IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN

            IF EXISTS
            (
                SELECT  TOP 1 1
                FROM    GEICO.dbo.ApplicationEntitySettingVal AESV (nolock)
                WHERE   AESV.Application_ID =  @Appl_ID_loc
                AND AESV.Setting_ID = @Set_ID_loc
                AND AESV.Entity_ID = @S_Ent_ID
                AND AESV.Status_ID = @AppEntSVal_Act
                AND AESV.Item_ID = @S_Itm_ID
            )
            BEGIN 
                SELECT  @SIntVal = AESV.intVal, 
                    @SrcEnt_ID = @S_Ent_ID
                FROM    GEICO.dbo.ApplicationEntitySettingVal AESV 
                WHERE   AESV.Application_ID =  @Appl_ID_loc
                AND AESV.Setting_ID = @Set_ID_loc
                AND AESV.Entity_ID = @S_Ent_ID
                AND AESV.Status_ID = @AppEntSVal_Act
                AND AESV.Item_ID = @S_Itm_ID

                IF @@error <> 0 
                BEGIN
                    CLOSE SettingChk
                    DEALLOCATE SettingChk
                    RETURN -999999999
                END

                --Exit the loop
                SET @UpstreamHit = 1
                BREAK
            END
        END -- Make sure Search_Item_ID is not null
    END -- Loop

    IF @UpstreamHit = 0 
    BEGIN
        RETURN -999999999
    END

    CLOSE SettingChk
    DEALLOCATE SettingChk       
END

SELECT
    @Error = @@Error

IF @Error <> 0
BEGIN
    SET @SIntVal = -999999999
END 

RETURN  @SIntVal
 END
```

I used SQL server.Please Anyone to find mistake of above function and resolve my problem. Thanks 
 in Advance.

Comment: Is this function slow when you initiate it from a select?

Comment: What about: you have a loop in a fuinction. Generally you bypass the optimizer AND combine that with a loop. AND use a cursor. 2 worst practices in one function. Time to hire a senrio developer to redo the architecture.

Comment: yes.initiate it from a select

Comment: @TomTom - what we have to solve this issue

Comment: Honestly, I'm not surprised that function is slow. Scalar Function have a tendancy for being (far) slower than a table-value function. Then you have a lot of calls inside that function; 2 `SELECT` statements setting variable values, more assignment, an `INSERT`, a `CURSOR` declaration, which you loop on `WHILE 10=10` and then a `BREAK`, rather than checking `@@FETCH_STATUS`, more assignment, more assignment, an `EXISTS`, and finally more assignment. Honestly, it's a mess for a Scalar function. I think we need to understand your real goal, and maybe we can help you rewrite it.

Comment: @Larnu  am just verify it existing this function.not created myself.dont know why they used While loop(10=10).

Comment: This code snipit is taken directly from stored procedure because
stored procedures can not be called from within functions

Comment: But Stored Procedures and Functions aren't the same thing. Don't treat them the same. And any Stored procedure written like that is going to perform awfully as well, in truth.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[GInterval](@App_ID int, @Setting_ID int,@Entity_ID int, @Item_ID int)
  RETURNS int 
 AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @SIntVal    int
DECLARE @Error      int


DECLARE @SP_Nme                 varchar(40)
DECLARE @H_Base             int
DECLARE @S_Ent_ID           int
DECLARE @S_Itm_ID               int
DECLARE @AppEntSet_Act  int
DECLARE @AppEntSVal_Act int
DECLARE @Appl_Item_ID       int
DECLARE @Usr_Ent_ID             int
DECLARE @Cl_Ent_ID          int
DECLARE @Ofc_Ent_ID         int
DECLARE @PrsCenter_Ent_ID   int
DECLARE @Appl_Ent_ID        int
DECLARE @UpstreamHit                tinyint
DECLARE @SrcEnt_ID              INT

DECLARE @Appl_ID_loc int
DECLARE @Set_ID_loc  int
DECLARE @Ent_ID_loc  int
DECLARE @Itm_ID_loc  int

SELECT @Appl_ID_loc=@App_ID, @Set_ID_loc=@Setting_ID, 
@Ent_ID_loc=@Entity_ID, @Itm_ID_loc=@Item_ID

SET     @SP_Nme                 = Object_Name(@@PROCID)
SET     @Usr_Ent_ID             = 1
SET     @Cl_Ent_ID          = 2
SET     @Ofc_Ent_ID         = 3
SET     @PrsCenter_Ent_ID   = 4
SET     @Appl_Ent_ID        = 5
SET     @AppEntSet_Act  = 297
SET     @AppEntSVal_Act = 299
SET     @UpstreamHit                = 0

SET @SIntVal=NULL
SET @SrcEnt_ID=NULL

SELECT  @SIntVal = AESV.intVal,
        @SrcEnt_ID = @Ent_ID_loc
FROM    GEICO.dbo.ApplicationEntitySettingVal AESV  WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE   AESV.Application_ID =  @Appl_ID_loc
AND AESV.Setting_ID = @Set_ID_loc
AND AESV.Entity_ID = @Ent_ID_loc
AND AESV.Status_ID = @AppEntSVal_Act
AND AESV.Item_ID = @Itm_ID_loc

IF @@error <> 0 
BEGIN
    RETURN -999999999
END

IF ((@SIntVal IS NULL) AND (@SrcEnt_ID IS NULL))
BEGIN



    SELECT  @H_Base = HierarchyRank
    FROM    GEICO.dbo.ApplicationEntitySetting AES  WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE   AES.Application_ID =  @Appl_ID_loc
    AND AES.Setting_ID = @Set_ID_loc
    AND AES.Entity_ID = @Ent_ID_loc

    IF @H_Base IS NULL
        SET @H_Base = 0

    DECLARE @upstream_temp TABLE (Entity_ID INT, Item_ID INT)   

    INSERT INTO @upstream_temp(Entity_ID,Item_ID)
    SELECT   Entity_ID,Item_ID FROM GEICO.dbo.fn_Setting_GetUpstreamIDs(@Ent_ID_loc, @Itm_ID_loc)

    DECLARE SettingChk cursor LOCAL FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY
    FOR
        SELECT  Entity_ID
        FROM    GEICO.dbo.ApplicationEntitySetting AES  WITH(NOLOCK)
        WHERE   AES.Application_ID =  @Appl_ID_loc
        AND AES.Setting_ID = @Set_ID_loc
        AND AES.Status_ID = @AppEntSVal_Act
        AND AES.HierarchyRank > @H_Base
        ORDER BY    AES.HierarchyRank


    OPEN SettingChk



                FETCH NEXT
                FROM    SettingChk
                INTO    @Search_Entity_ID

                IF (@@fetch_status <> 0)
                BEGIN
                    CLOSE SettingChk
                    DEALLOCATE SettingChk
                    BREAK
                END



                SELECT  @S_Itm_ID = Item_ID FROM    @upstream_temp
                WHERE Entity_ID = @S_Ent_ID

                --Need to get application ID since it was not returned by the function of getupstreamids.
                if @S_Ent_ID = @Appl_Ent_ID 
                    SELECT  @S_Itm_ID =  @Appl_ID_loc


                    IF @S_Itm_ID IS NOT NULL
                    BEGIN

                                        IF EXISTS
                                        (
                                            SELECT  TOP 1 
                                            FROM    GEICO.dbo.ApplicationEntitySettingVal AESV WITH(nolock)
                                            WHERE   AESV.Application_ID =  @Appl_ID_loc
                                            AND AESV.Setting_ID = @Set_ID_loc
                                            AND AESV.Entity_ID = @S_Ent_ID
                                            AND AESV.Status_ID = @AppEntSVal_Act
                                            AND AESV.Item_ID = @S_Itm_ID
                                        )
                                        BEGIN 
                                            SELECT  @SIntVal = AESV.intVal, 
                                                @SrcEnt_ID = @S_Ent_ID
                                            FROM    GEICO.dbo.ApplicationEntitySettingVal AESV  WITH(nolock)
                                            WHERE   AESV.Application_ID =  @Appl_ID_loc
                                            AND AESV.Setting_ID = @Set_ID_loc
                                            AND AESV.Entity_ID = @S_Ent_ID
                                            AND AESV.Status_ID = @AppEntSVal_Act
                                            AND AESV.Item_ID = @S_Itm_ID

                                            IF @@error <> 0 
                                            BEGIN
                                                CLOSE SettingChk
                                                DEALLOCATE SettingChk
                                                RETURN -999999999
                                            END

                                            --Exit the loop
                                            SET @UpstreamHit = 1
                                            BREAK
                                        END
                    END -- Make sure Search_Item_ID is not null


    IF @UpstreamHit = 0 
    BEGIN
        RETURN -999999999
    END

    CLOSE SettingChk
    DEALLOCATE SettingChk       
END

SELECT
    @Error = @@Error

IF @Error <> 0
BEGIN
    SET @SIntVal = -999999999
END 

RETURN  @SIntVal
 END
```

Comment: How does this improve the function? It still suffers all of the problems it did before.